# Why doesn't spread attributes work with React useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm keeping state in a functional component using the useState hook and want to update a single value without having to explicitly set all other attributes, so I thought using the spread operator would work, but it does not!

This is my state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  data: [],
  currentIndex: 0,
  editMode: false
});
```

Can someone explain why this doesn't work...

```
setState({ editMode: value, ...state });
```

...when this does:

```
setState({ editMode: value, data: [], currentIndex: 0 });
```

Whats the difference? Can I use the spread operator or have I misunderstood something?

Here is a [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-surf-jsk7v) to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reverse the order:

```
setState({ ...state, editMode: value });
```

Otherwise, you are overwriting `editMode`'s value with the old value.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about the order. Think about the following:

```js
const state = {
  data: [],
  currentIndex: 0,
  editMode: false
};
const value = true;

const result = { editMode: value, ...state };
const result2 = { editMode: value, data: [], currentIndex: 0 };
const result3 = { ...state, editMode: value };

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Doing `{ editMode: value, ...state }` is equivelent to:

```
{                                   {
  editMode: value,                    
  data: [],                           data: [],
  currentIndex: 0,      ------->      currentIndex: 0,
  editMode: false                     editMode: false
}                                   }
```

As keys cannot be repeated in objects, the last `editMode` key-value pair overwrites the first, thus removing the first `editMode: value`. Instead, you can spread first:

```
{...state, editMode: value}
```

This will overwrite the `editMode` in your `state` with the new object `editMode`:

```
{                                   {
  data: [],                           data: [],
  currentIndex: 0,                    currentIndex: 0,
  editMode: false,      ------->      
  editMode: value,                    editMode: value,
}                                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the `Object` with `useState` hook use this function syntax:

```
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, editMode: value }));
```